# Creating a password with only numbers and digits using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, passwords

I am making a program that takes a string from a user to create a password. However, this password needs to be at least 8 characters or more, and it can only include letters(uppercase and lowercase) and digits. I already did this, however, when I enter in the user input a blank space(ex: "pass word") or a special symbol such as "%" or "&", the method still returns the value true, making the password valid when it shouldn't return this, how do I correct this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Password
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your password");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pass = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is the password valid? " + passwordCheck(pass));
    }
    
    public static boolean passwordCheck(String password)
    {   
        boolean pass = false;
        for(int i=0; i < password.length(); i++)
        {
        char c = password.charAt(i);
        if(password.length() >= 8)
        {
            if(c >= 48 && c <= 57)
            {
            pass = true;    
            }
            else if(c>= 97 && c<= 122)
            {
            pass = true; 
            }
            else if(c>=65 && c<=90)
            {
            pass = true;    
            }
            else if(c == 32)
            {
            pass = false;    
            }
        }    
        
        
        }
        return pass;

    }
}
```

Comment: sure, you don't wanna use regex??

Comment: One suggestion , please take out the if statement in for loop , it will unnecessarily run , if password length is less than 8

Comment: One problem is that each time you find a "good" character in the loop you reset the flag to true ... irrespective of what it was before.  So if the last character of the password is OK, it ignores the possibility that earlier ones were OK.  Understand the logic that you have written and fix it.

Comment: `if (userInputString.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}")) { System.out.println("Password Good!"); }`

Answer (score 0):

you need to break out of the loop once it encounters a space or any other special character.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Password
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your password");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pass = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is the password valid? " + passwordCheck(pass));
    }
    
    public static boolean passwordCheck(String password)
    {   
        boolean pass = false;
        for(int i=0; i < password.length(); i++)
        {
        char c = password.charAt(i);
        if(password.length() >= 8)
        {
            // also you can directly mention the character instead of looking for its respective ASCII value
            if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                pass = true;
            }
            else if(c>= 'a' && c<= 'z')
            {
                pass = true; 
            }
            else if(c>='A' && c<='Z')
            {
                pass = true;
            }
            else // loop will break if it encounters a space or any other 
 special character
            {
                pass = false;    
                break;
            }
        }    
        
        
        }
        return pass;

    }
}
```